# How to obtain Thread Certified source code of OpenThread proye t

Tags: openthread

On [OpenThread Certification Prerequisites](https://openthread.io/certification/prerequisites) say

> Note: Only the OpenThread reference firmware images provided as part of the Thread Test Harness release are officially supported by the Thread Group.

There is no tag or branch in OpenThread repository that indicate the source code of this version.

How to obtain this commit or source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag for Thread Test Harness V1.1 R1.2.0 has been published on GitHub [here](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/releases/tag/thread-reference-20170716).

Comment: But this is not possible. The tag commit is dated 2017-07-15 and the certification date is 2017-02-07 ???

Comment: The OpenThread reference firmware included in Thread Test Harness V1.1 R1.2.0 is dated 2017-07-16.